# Perl regex multiline match without dot

Tags: regex, perl, multiline, exact-match

There are numerous questions on how to do a multiline regex in Perl. Most of them mention the `s` switch that makes a dot match a newline. However, I want to match an exact phrase (so, not a pattern) and I don't know where the newlines will be. So the question is: can you *ignore* newlines, instead of matching them with `.`?

MWE:

```
$pattern = "Match this exact phrase across newlines";

$text1 = "Match\nthis exact\nphrase across newlines";
$text2 = "Match this\nexact phra\nse across\nnewlines";

$text3 = "Keep any newlines\nMatch this exact\nphrase across newlines\noutside\nof the match";

$text1 =~ s/$pattern/replacement text/s;
$text2 =~ s/$pattern/replacement text/s;
$text3 =~ s/$pattern/replacement text/s;

print "$text1\n---\n$text2\n---\n$text3\n";
```

I can put dots in the pattern instead of spaces (`"Match.this.exact.phrase"`) but that does not work for the second example. I can delete all newlines as preprocessing but I would like to keep newlines that are not part of the match (as in the third example).

Desired output:

```
replacement text
---
replacement text
---
Keep any newlines
replacement text
outside
of the match
```

Comment: Most of the time, you are treating newlines as spaces. Then there's the one time you want to ignore it. Doing either is easy. Doing both is next to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to change your "exact" pattern to match newlines anywhere, and also to allow newlines instead of spaces.  So change your pattern to do so:

```
$pattern = "Match this exact phrase across newlines";
$pattern =~ s/\S\K\B/\n?/g;
$pattern =~ s/ /[ \n]/g;
```

Comment: Note: This assumes `$pattern` is not a regex pattern, but a string literal to find exactly.

Comment: This won't match is `$pattern = "*"` and `$text = "*"`.

Comment: This won't match if `$pattern = "foo-bar"` and `$text = "foo\n-bar"`.

Comment: @ikegami I was assuming no regex metacharacters, yes.  But not thinking about other non-word chars. Use ikegami's answer instead

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the literal spaces with a character class that matches a space or a newline:

```
$pattern = "Match[ \n]this[ \n]exact[ \n]phrase[ \n]across[ \n]newlines";
```

Or, if you want to be more lenient, use `\s` or `\s+` instead, since `\s` also matches newlines.

Comment: how about my second example (`phra\nse`)?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, you are treating newlines as spaces. If that's all you wanted to do, all you'd need is

```
$text =~ s/\n/ /g;
$text =~ /\Q$text_to_find/    # or $text =~ /$regex_pattern_to_match/
```

Then there's the one time you want to ignore it. If that's all you wanted to do, all you'd need is

```
$text =~ s/\n//g;
$text =~ /\Q$text_to_find/    # or $text =~ /$regex_pattern_to_match/
```

Doing both is next to impossible if you have a regex pattern to match. But you seem to want to match literal text, so that opens up some possibilities.

```
( my $pattern = $text_to_find )
   =~ s/(.)/ $1 eq " " ? "[ \\n]" : "\\n?" . quotemeta($1) /seg;
$pattern =~ s/^\\n\?//;
$text =~ /$pattern/
```

Comment: Tested. Made a couple of fixes.

Comment: I think that strips a newline just before the desired match

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is ugly, but it works:

```
M\n?a\n?t\n?c\n?h\st\n?h\n?i\n?s\se\n?x\n?a\n?ct\sp\n?h\n?r\n?a\n?s\n?e\sa\n?c\n?r\n?o\n?s\n?s\sn\n?e\n?w\n?l\n?i\n?n\n?e\n?s
```

For every pair of letters inside a word, allow a newline between them  with `\n?`. And replace each space in your regex with `\s`.

May not be usable, but it gets the job done ;)

[Check it out at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zS6vM2/1).